# Пошаговая анимация

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Нужно чтобы при щелчке внешний блок появлялся с помощью функции slideDown, и только после его появления внутренний абзац появлялся c помощью анимации

```js
$('.imag').click(function(){
    $('div:last').slideDown(1000,function(){
        $('div:last p').animate(
        {
            opacity: 1;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
div:last-of-type {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40%;
    top:30%;
    padding-top:20px;
    background: gray;
    display: none;
}
div:last-of-type p {
    opacity: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="imag">123</span>
<div>
    <p>Заголовок заголовок</p>
    <img src="../1304109321_324_1280.jpg" alt="картинка" style="width:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.hiddenDiv').slideDown(1000);
 
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hiddenDiv p').animate({ opacity: 1 });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.hiddenDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40%;
  top: 30%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: gray;
  display: none;
}
.hiddenDiv p {
  opacity: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <span class="button">Кнопка</span>
  <div class="hiddenDiv">
    <p>Заголовок заголовок</p>
    <img src="http://www.sourceoneinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/IMG_Client.png">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял то ошибка в синтаксисе

```
$('.imag').click(function() {
    $('div:last').slideDown(1000, function() {
        $('div:last p').animate({
            opacity: 1 //тут без ;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: да, вы меня правильно поняли

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.b-button {
  display: none;
}
.b-button + label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 15%;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: .3s;
}
.b-button:checked + label {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
}
.b-button:checked + label ~ .b-inner {
  max-height: 500px;
}
.b-inner {
  background: #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
.b-inner > h3 {
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
  animation: animTitle 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes animTitle {
  0%, 50% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button" class="b-button">
  <label for="button">button</label>

  <div class="b-inner">
    <h3>Заголовок заголовок</h3>
    <img src="http://www.sourceoneinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/IMG_Client.png">
  </div>
</div>
```